# how can I refresh my listview?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want my listview in WPF to have no highlighted previous selections. How can I refresh my listview so that there are no highlighted selections?

I don't want to clear the data and again fetch it from the server.

Kindly help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF - How to clear selection from ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098213/wpf-how-to-clear-selection-from-listview)

Comment: If you use databinding for the SelectedItem doesn't it work if you set it to null inside your ViewModel?

Comment: Thank you so much. The issue got resolved from your help :)

Comment: @user2276352 Added answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use databinding for the SelectedItem it'll work if you set it to null inside your ViewModel.